# Columns are said to be null while they really aren't C# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have created a datagridview with a nested relation that lists an incident and its activities per row. This by using DevExpress:

[image]

My problem is, is that I do not have access right to the columns at all.

This means that I can't set the hidden columns, column widths and so an all by a `NullReferenceException`.

This is my code that I use:

```
 private void DisplayData()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Ticketing;Integrated Security=true");
        daIncidents = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from incidents", conn);
        daActivities = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Activity", conn);
        ds = new DataSet();

        daIncidents.Fill(ds, "Incidents");
        daActivities.Fill(ds, "Activities");

        DataColumn keyColumn = ds.Tables["Incidents"].Columns["IncidentID"];
        DataColumn foreignKeyColumn = ds.Tables["Activities"].Columns["IncidentID"];
        ds.Relations.Add("IncidentsActivities", keyColumn, foreignKeyColumn);

        gridControl.DataSource = ds.Tables["Incidents"];
        gridControl.ForceInitialize();

        GridView gridView = new GridView(gridControl);

        gridControl.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("IncidentsActivities", gridView);
        gridView.ViewCaption = "Activities";

        //gridView.Columns["ActivityID"].ReadOnly = true; 
        //gridView.Columns["Description"].Width = 40;
    }
```

Why does it say that the columns are null if they really aren't? I have tried using `int`as index but same problem.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: last lines in commentary

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the final `}` and then debug to it (so it breaks on the breakpoint) and then type in `?gridView.Columns` in your `Immediate` window, what do you see?

Comment: I used `Columns.Count()` and it says they're 0 just before the column edit. But if I don't do a column edit and count the columns, it's also 0. Where do I edit the columns then?

Comment: Do these links help? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B204415/gridview-columns-count-is-zero-when-using-xpinstantfeedback-datasource https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q275799/gridview-columns-empty-even-after-gridview-populatecolumns https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T207383/gridview-columns-is-empty-after-specifying-gridcontrol-datasource

Comment: Sadly I have checked them already. But my code should look fine no? Like it's not a code-related problem right?µ

Comment: The fixes from those article mention fixing it at compile time or adding lines like `.ForceInitialise()´. Didn't help for me or unrelated for me

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
gridView.ViewCaption = "Activities";
```

to:

```
gridView.ViewCaption = "Activities";
gridView.PopulateColumns();
```

Comment: Same problem :/